# PublishPipelineArtifact@0 fails with "API resource location not registered"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1 with current agent version: '2.153.1'

I'm trying to build a staged build/test/publish yaml. After the build I'd like to publish the artifact to the pipeline, because testing has special requirements and should/could be run on a dedicated agent.

The task inside that stage/job:

```
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
        inputs:
          artifactName: ReadyBuilt
          targetPath: $(OutputDirectory)
```

(Sidenote: I can't use PublishPipelineArtifact@1 from the online documentation, as our version is on premise and doesn't support it yet.)

It results in packing but fails on publishing.

```
##[section]Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Pipeline Artifact
Description  : Publish Pipeline Artifact
Version      : 0.139.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : Publish a local directory or file as a named artifact for the current pipeline.
==============================================================================
Uploading pipeline artifact from C:\work\tfs-agent\_work\23\s\Project\build for build #8348
Information, DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session a0724b96-007e-48e5-861a-da10242fffce
Information, 347 files to be processed in 4 groups.
Information, 47 out of 347 files processed (Group: 4/4)
Information, 147 out of 347 files processed (Group: 1/4)
Information, 247 out of 347 files processed (Group: 3/4)
Information, 347 out of 347 files processed (Group: 2/4)
Information, Processed 347 files from C:\work\tfs-agent\_work\23\s\Project\build successfully.
Information, Uploading 347 files from: C:\work\tfs-agent\_work\23\s\Project\build
Information, Uploaded 0.0 MB out of 304.8 MB.
##[error]API resource location 53e6e1e0-[...] is not registered on https://azuredevsrv/DefaultCollection/.
##[section]Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PublishPipelineArtifacts is not supported on Azure Devop 2019 Update 1.1.  Only in the cloud service.  You can use what @shamrai-aleksander proposed.

[image]

Comment: That concerns PublishPipelineArtifact@1.

(Other tasks in the on premise Azure DevOps are badly documented too. Only documentation for the latest online version of a task seems to be available.)

Comment: @Leonidas usually you can use the dropdown below version on the top left-handed side and pick the version you have and it will show you information about that version.  In the case of PublishPipelineArtifacts when you select TFS 2019 or below you get the green bar at the top and it puts you back to Azure DevOps service.  So it's not supported in those version.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue and I`ve added a new ticket to the developers community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/937338/publishpipelineartifact-fails-with-message-api-res.html.

As workaround. You can use `PublishBuildArtifacts` task with `CopyFiles` task.

The example for .net:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
     publishLocation: Container
```